# JavaScript + OLEDB + Oracle Stored Procedure+vbscript

Tags: javascript, stored-procedures, oledbcommand

I have a **HTA** tool developed using JavaScript. It connects to backend Oracle database and perform the operation.

DMLs are running fine but PLSQL doesn't run.

How to run a Oracle stored procedure using OLEDB in JavaScript.

For normal SQL queries, am using below command

```
    try {
            var connection = new ActiveXObject('ADODB.Connection'); 
            //alert(RepoConnStr);
            connection.open(RepoConnStr);

        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);       
            return;
        }
    try {
            SQL = "SELECT unique job_name as job_name FROM DATPRD.JMS_JOB_INVENTORY";
            var rows = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
            rows.open(SQL,connection);
            while(rows.EOF == false)
            {

                Job_Name_List=Job_Name_List.concat(rows("job_name")).concat("\n");
                rows.MoveNext();
            }
            //alert(DB_Details);
            rows.close();
        }
        catch (e) {
            alert(e);
            alert("Unable to Fetch Job Name List");
            window.location.reload(1);
        }
```

But it doesn't work with stored Proc. Can someone help me with the syntax for stored Proc? I need to execute `stored_Porc(param1,param2)`. Both parameters are input variable.  I am OK with either JavaScript or VBScript.

Comment: Show us the code you're using to connect to Oracle via OLEDB and run DMLs in JavaScript, and we might be able to help.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add all relevant code to the question itself.

Comment: I just updated my question with more info. Thanks

Comment: Can someone please help me get the solution. I have googled lot of code and tried it but it fails for one reason or another.

Answer (score 0):

Directly from javascript isn't possible.

One way to do this is create a webservice or something to work back-end and execute your stored procedure, then call the webservice from javascript with (jquery) ajax or another method